# How to add an image from my computer instead of a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, url

I would like to find out how to add custom images from my computer instead of a website url in javascript. I am also having trouble with some of the image links online not loading because the code isn't accepting the file extensions such as .jpg or .png.

```js
var IMAGE_SOURCE = "";
var IMAGE_EXTENSION = "";

// const IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://example.com/images/";
// const IMAGE_EXTENSION = ".png";

function tests() {
  let combo = document.getElementById("string_determine");
  let div = document.getElementById("mybox");
  let string_determine;

  switch (combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text) {
    case '"red" + "blue"':
      string_determine = "purple";
      div.style.color = "purple";
      IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/small/178-1782199_teardrop-dark-purple-clip-art-purple-raindrop-clipart";
      break;
    case '"blue" + "green"':
      string_determine = "turquoise";
      div.style.color = "turquoise";
      IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5hBnmIKpz6s7CMswHyFSogMfvrFGuFI41hA&usqp=CAU";
      break;
    case '"green" + "red"':
      string_determine = "brown";
      div.style.color = "brown";
      IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKjT9rxtmqaih5btmho6cPqDrcW3RXxBmc1w&usqp=CAU";
      break;
      
    default:
      string_determine = "NONE";
  }

  let myBoxHTML = `<p>${string_determine}</p><img src="${IMAGE_SOURCE}${string_determine}${IMAGE_EXTENSION}">`;
  console.log(myBoxHTML);
  document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = myBoxHTML;
}
```

```html
<select name="string_determine" id="string_determine">
  <option value=>Select Value</option>
  <option value='"red" + "blue"'>"red" + "blue"</option>
  <option value='"blue" + "green"'>"blue" + "green"</option>
  <option value='"green" + "red"'>"green" + "red"</option>
</select>

<button onclick="tests()">Yes</button>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Selection</h3>
  <div id="mybox" class="box">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: To use a local file, the user has to select it from a file dialog, then you can read it with the `File` API, and create a `data:` URL to use as the image source.

Answer (score 2):

Local file paths in js do not work, because of sandboxing.

You likely have to set up a local web server and then use localhost urls.